# MySQL backup not getting restored properly

Tags: mysql, restore, database-backups

I am running MariaDB in a Ubuntu 20.04 system. I backed up my `mysql` database with:

```
mysqldump -u root -p mysql > mysql_backup.sql
```

And then I created a new table in the `mysql` database

```
use mysql;
create table foo(line blob);
```

Then I restored my backup (without deleting the `foo` table in the mysql database)

```
mysql -u root -p mysql < mysql_backup.sql
```

Now, when I try to create a table named `foo` it gives this error saying it already exists.

```
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'foo' already exists
```

Shouldn't the restore process overwrite the existing database and restore the previous data?

Comment: Short answer: No.   (Longer answer: ) The restore add the info from the backup file to the current database.  If you decide do delete the table `foo`, you should do a `DROP TABLE foo;`   (or restore your backup to a different database)

Comment: What if I just want to revert back to the backup? Is there anyway to do that without backing up to a different database?

Comment: Yes, you can remove/re-create the database, before restoring the backup.  Or, you can add the `-B` option, which will add the `CREATE DATABASE  ...; USE ....` statement to your backup file.                         BTW: I would default to use another database then `mysql`, becuase that database has also info on the created users (and more....).

Comment: I added `-B` to the `mysqldump` command. But it still gives the same error.

Comment: With the `-B` option, the `CREATE DATABASE ...` is added, not the `DROP DATABASE ...`.